# How to select only text in a div containg other div in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have this code :

```
<div class="bodytext1typeenc">Ce qu’il faut retenir
    <div class="al">Budget «solidarités».</div>
</div>
```

I want to get only "Ce qu’il faut retenir". I've tried this :

```
$('.bodytext1typeenc').text() // --> doesn't work.
$('.bodytext1typeenc').remove('.al') //  --> doesn't work.
```

Any help please ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey try this instead what you want to do is clone your element then remove your child elements

http://jsfiddle.net/HgdyG/

```
$(".bodytext1typeenc")
        .clone()    //clone the element
        .children() //select all the children
        .remove()   //remove all the children
        .end()  //again go back to selected element
        .text();
```

If you where going to use this alot you could create a simple extension like this

```
jQuery.fn.noChild= function() {

    return $(this).clone()
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .text();

};
```

Then run

```
$(".bodytext1typeenc").noChild();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works just fine. I'm astonished by the speed of your answers at my first question on Stackoverflow ;-) Thanks again !

Comment: No problem good luck with your project. Dont forget to choose an answer as an accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You could clone, remove the children and get the text. See below,

```
var $clone = $('.bodytext1typeenc').clone();
$clone.children().remove()
$clone.text(); //should return the div's text
```

**Note:** You don't need to clone if you don't want to preserve the original content.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/PX2yA/

Answer (score 0):

You could use contents() and filter out the noteType TEXT_NODE (3)

```
var val = $('.bodytext1typeenc').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).text();
val = $.trim(val);

alert('"' + val + '"'); // "Ce qu’il faut retenir"
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/AsilIpo/1/

Comment: It works too, thanks, but I don't understand how ;-)

Comment: @FabienfromParis I recommend you read: http://api.jquery.com/contents/ about the  contents block, then we just filter out all the collection that matches the filter method (see if the nodeType is a text_node).